# Ignoring merge commits for prepare-commit-msg git hook

Tags: git, githooks

I came up with the following prepare-commit-msg git hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH=`git branch | grep '^*' | sed -e 's/^\* //'`
MESSAGE=`cat "$1"`
JIRA_ID=$(echo "$BRANCH" | grep -Eo "[A-Z0-9]{1,10}-?[A-Z0-9]+-\d+")

if [ -z "$JIRA_ID" ]; then
    echo "$MESSAGE" > "$1"
else
    echo "[$JIRA_ID] $MESSAGE" > "$1"
fi
```

It does its job by adding branch name (which is in a form of BRANCH-123) to every commit message. However, I don't want this to work with merge commits which have auto-generate commit messages s.a. `Merge branch 'master' into BRANCH-123`. Which with my hook converts into `BRANCH-123 Merge branch 'master' into BRANCH-123`

I need to edit the script to somehow ignore (not apply the hook) commits starting with `Merge branch`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the document of [prepare-commit-msg](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) says,

> It takes one to three parameters. The first is the name of the file
> that contains the commit log message. The second is the source of the
> commit message, and can be: message (if a -m or -F option was given);
> template (if a -t option was given or the configuration option
> commit.template is set); merge (if the commit is a merge or a
> .git/MERGE_MSG file exists); squash (if a .git/SQUASH_MSG file
> exists); or commit, followed by a commit SHA-1 (if a -c, -C or --amend
> option was given).

We can test the 2nd parameter and exit with 0 if it's `merge`:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
SHA1=$3

if [ "${COMMIT_SOURCE}" = merge ];then
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: On a previous day I really searched high and low for this, then today 1st Google and 'blam'! Thankyou

Comment: If it is rebase how can we solve this issue?

Comment: @atadnmz During a rebase, a temporary directory `.git/rebase-merge/` exists for a while. You could test if it exists to distinguish a rebase from a merge.